# NPOI: how to use custom XSSFColor in conditional formatting?

Tags: c#, excel, conditional-formatting, npoi, xssf

What I have:

```
var sheetCf = sheet.SheetConditionalFormatting;
var rule = sheetCf.CreateConditionalFormattingRule("A2>0");
var fill = rule.CreatePatternFormatting();

fill.FillBackgroundColor = IndexedColors.Red.Index;
fill.FillPattern = (short)FillPattern.SolidForeground;
```

How can I set Custom color for background?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

```
XSSFCellStyle myCellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
myCellStyle.FillBackgroundColor = IndexedColors.LightYellow.Index;
myCellStyle.FillPattern = FillPattern.NoFill;
myCellStyle.FillForegroundColor = IndexedColors.LightTurquoise.Index;
```